# Numero aleatorio entre 5 y 15 Java

Tags: java

Necesito generar un numero aleatorio entre 5 y 15. Quiero hacerlo con `Math.Random()` , no usando la clase `Random`.

Comment: Hola Sergio AG, ¿qué has intentado? ¿con qué problemas/dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones para mejorar tus preguntas y que sean mejor recibidas.

Comment: ¿Como pretendes que ponga un ejemplo si no se como se hace directamente?

Comment: Algo habrás intentado, ¿no? Quieres hacerlo con `Math.Random()`, ¿cómo has intentado usar `Math.Random`? ¿le has pasado parámetros? ¿Te aparece algún error? Ayuda al resto de usuarios a ayudarte: comparte lo que hayas investigado o intentado.

Comment: un ejemplo sería: probé  `System.out.print(Math.Random()*10+5);` me da números arriba de 100, o con decimales, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Si quisieramos valores entre dos números cualquiera ambos incluídos, por ejemplo, 5 y 10, la cuenta sería (maximo-minimimo)+1, es decir, (10-5)+1 = 6, también multiplicaríamos por 6.

```
 Math.random()*6   // Esto da valores de 0.0 a 6.0, excluido el 6.0
```

Como nuestro primer valor es 1, le sumamos 1 al resultado. En el caso de que quisieramos entre 5 y 10, habría que sumar 5, es decir, el valor mínimo.

```
 Math.random()*6 + 1   // Esto da valores entre 1.0 y 7.0 excluido el 7.0
```

Finalmente, para conseguir un entero, quitamos los decimales usando la clase Math.floor()

```
 int valorDado = Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
```

En general, para conseguir un número entero entre M y N con M menor que N y ambos incluídos, debemos usar esta fórmula

```
 int valorEntero = Math.floor(Math.random()*(N-M+1)+M);  // Valor entre M y N, ambos incluidos.
```

Si no queremos un valor entero sino double, la fórmula es sin el +1

```
 double valorAleatorio = Math.random()*(N-M)+M;
```

eso sí, recuerda que el valor N queda excluido y no saldrá nunca.

Este es el artículo completo.
http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Generar_n%C3%BAmeros_aleatorios_en_Java

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza la libreria Math.random.
Para hallar numeros aleatorios entre X y Y la formula es esta:

```
int numero = (int)(Math.random()*(X-Y+1)+Y;
```

Comment: Aunque esta respuesta sirve para resolver el problema, sería ideal si pudieras explicar cómo funciona el código.

Comment: Coincido con Alvaro. Te agredeceria que explicaras más a fondo tu respuesta.